# Why do I need to update uvs?

Tags: three.js

I'm working with the three.js editor where I parse an object from JSON format. As usual it first parses the materials and geometries, then I create meshes from it. While parsing materials I also load textures. The issue now is that I have to call...

`object.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
object.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;`

... after the image for the texture completely loaded - but why?! The geometry never changed before, neither did its uvs or anything like it. It's still the plain old geometry, yet I always get a `GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2` when trying to render. It only works with this "hack" although the geometry is always the same.

In my opinion it should also work perfectly when I update the uvs after object creation (or not at all). I didn't find anything in the three.js editor code that would update the geometry or its faceVertexUvs.

I know it's a bit of an abstract problem, I'm mainly looking for some hints or insights why this hack might be necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: could this be an issue with the way three.js constructs its shaders and buffers in regards to the parameters? Say when you call meshlambertmaterial, without the map parameter, i think you end up with a shader that has no reference to uvs at all. No reference, no need to buffer a bunch of floats. I'm totally guessing here, i hope someone answers better.

Comment: A good guess, which I initially threw away because I _explicitely_ called uvsNeedUpdate beforehand. And I figured that with this explicit call the "compiler" wouldn't just "not do it". But since you got this idea too I'll investigate in the matter.

Comment: Haha it was exactly this ^^

Comment: Hmm well I can't accept a comment. But if you want you can create an answer,I'll accept that one and delete my own

Comment: lol no worries j/k :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js "guesses" whether uvs are needed according to your used textures in `bufferGuessUVType`. If you want to preallocate uv buffers you can either init a map attribute with an empty `THREE.Texture`, update the geometry after the map was assigned, etc.